# Netbeans CVS - existing repo - existing working copy

Tags: version-control, netbeans, cvs

I'm using Netbeans to develop with Drupal.  I'm trying to let Netbeans get drupal core and modules from the repository on drupal.org to my local working copy.  Problem is: I already have a working copy that is not versioned yet.

When I try to checkout a copy from drupal.org, Netbeans asks if I want to create a new project - I don't.  How can I turn my local copy into a "checked out" working copy?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I have no experience with Netbeans CVS integration, so the following are just assumptions/ideas based on Netbeans handling many things similar to Eclipse. Make sure that you have a working backup of your project before trying any of these.

---

1. I would expect Netbeans to have an option to check out into an existing project as well (what happens if you say 'no' when asked to create a new project?).
2. If there is no option for this, you could try to check out into a new project first and then copy the contents of the new project to your existing project outside of Netbeans with normal file system operations (excluding any Netbeans specific files, but including the CVS folders).
3. Another option would be to do the checkout outside of Netbeans in the first place, using the command line or some other CVS tool on the file system representation of your project.

Comment: as a netbeans user: you should do the 2.